# Continuous decomposition into sum of vectors along sum of linear subspaces

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, proof-verification, normed-spaces

I'm trying to prove that Minkowsky sum of relative interiors of two convex sets is contained in the relative interior of the sum. I need the following lemma to complete the proof:

assume that $U$ and $W$ are finite dimensional subspaces of Banach space $V$.

> Is it true that for all positive real $\varepsilon$ it is possible to find some positive real number $\delta$ such that for every vector $v \in U + W$ with $\|v\| \le  \delta$ it is possible to find vectors $u \in U$ and $w \in W$ such that $v = w + u $ and $\| w\|< \varepsilon$ and $\| v \| < \varepsilon$? Or in language of quantors: $$ \forall \varepsilon \in \mathbb{R}_{++} \; . \;\exists \delta \in \mathbb{R}_{++} \; : \; \forall v \in U + W : \|v\| \le \delta \; . \; \exists w \in W \; : \; \exists u \in U \; : \quad  :v = u + w \; \And \; \|w\| < \varepsilon \;  \And \; \|u\| < \varepsilon $$

Looking at the quantified statement it seems that the problem can be restated as the problem of existence of  function $f : W + U \to W \times U $  continuous at $0$ with $f(0) = (0,0)$, and at least locally at $0$ providing the sum property $v = w + u$ with $f(v) = (w,u)$.

I tried going with contrapositive:
Assume that there exists sequence  of vectors $v_n \in W + U$  with $\lim_{n \to \infty} v_n = 0$, such that every decomposition $v_n =w_n + u_n$ (that necessarily exists) has property that $\|w_n\| \ge \varepsilon$ and $\|u_n\| \ge \varepsilon$. Assume, first, that the sum is direct i. e. $v_n \in U \oplus W$ so we have no choice while selecting $u_n$ and $w_n$. Then
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} u_n + w_n  =0  $$
implying 
$$
 \lim_{n \to \infty} \Big\|u_n - (-w_n)\Big\| =0. 
$$
If both sequences $u_n$ and $w_n$ have same converging subsequence then their partial limits $u\in U$ and $w \in W$ (as both subspaces are closed) are and non zero and have $u = -w$, hence, $U \cap W \neq \{0\}$, a contradiction.  But if one sequence is converging for a subsequence of indices, then the other must also stabilize. Indeed, $u_n + w_n$ is Cauchy:
$$ \| v_{n_k} - v_{n_l} \|=\|u_{n_k} + w_{n_k} - u_{n_l}  - w_{n_l}\| \ge \Big| \| u_{n_k} - u_{n_l} \| - \| w_{n_k} - w_{n_l}\| \Big|.  
 $$
So if $u$ is Cauchy for some subsequence, $w$ must be also Cauchy and hence converging. This provides us with the property
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \|u_n\| = \infty$$ and 
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \| - w_n\| =\lim_{n \to \infty} \| w_n\| = \infty $$
as we may assume our space to be locally compact. This must imply that $ \lim_{n \to \infty} \|u_n -(-w_n)\| \neq 0 $ as vectors of high norm in trivially intersecting vector spaces must be detached and $W \cap U = \{0\}$
. This provides a contradiction.

In case $U + W \neq U \oplus W$ we can select subspace $W'$ of $W$ such that $ W = U \cap W \oplus W'$, then $U + W = U \oplus W'$ and we achieve similar result.

Is my reasoning correct?

Is there a simpler proof?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, you haven't used the finite-dimensionality of $U$ and $W$.

Assume that the sum is direct, i.e. $U \cap W = \{0\}$.

Let $B = \{u_1, \ldots, u_m, w_1, \ldots, w_n\}$ be a basis for $U + W$, where $u_1, \ldots, u_m \in U$ and $w_1, \ldots, w_n \in W$.

Define a norm $\|\cdot\|_{B, \infty}$ on $U + W$ like this:

$$\left\|\sum_{i=1}^m{\alpha_i}u_i + \sum_{j=1}^n \beta_jw_j\right\|_{B, \infty} = \max\{|\alpha_1|, \ldots, |\alpha_m|, |\beta_1|, \ldots, |\beta_n|\}$$

Since $U + W$ is finite-dimensional, all norms are equivalent so there exist constants $m, M > 0$ such that:

$$m\|x\|_{B, \infty} \le \|x\| \le M\|x\|_{B, \infty}, \text{ for all }x \in U + W$$

Now let $\varepsilon > 0$ and pick $\delta = \frac{m}{M}\cdot\frac{\varepsilon}2$.

For any $v \in U + W$ such that $\|v\| \le \delta$ take $u \in U$ and $v \in W$ such that $v = u + w$. Notice that $\|u\|_{B, \infty}, \|w\|_{B, \infty} \le \|v\|_{B, \infty}$.

We have:

$$\frac{m}{M}\max\{\|u\|, \|w\|\} \le m\max\{\|u\|_{B, \infty}, \|w\|_{B, \infty}\} \le m\|v\|_{B, \infty} \le \|v\| \le \delta = \frac{m}{M}\cdot\frac{\varepsilon}2$$

Hence, $$\max\{\|u\|, \|w\|\}  \le \frac{\varepsilon}2 < \varepsilon$$

As you suggest, if $U \cap W \ne \{0\}$, then $U + W = U \oplus W'$ so you could run this argument again.

Comment: Thanks for participation. I think your proof is correct.  In fact, the finite dimension of $W + U$ was implicitly used in the last part of proof to get compactness of bounded balls, and hence assure existence of converging subsequences in case $\| w_n \|$ and $\| u_n\|$ are not approaching infinity.